# Handling 16 bpp tiff file in C++

Tags: c++, image, tiff

I need to open 16 bpp grayscale tiff image in C++ program. Trying to do this with GDI+ Image class, I get OutOfMemoryException (GDI+ doesn't support 16 bpp format). Standard Windows tools, like Paint and Picture Viewer, cannot open such image, possibly they use GDI or GDI+. ImageJ program opens such image successfully.
Is there some SDK which can open such images and give access to image raw data? If not, I need TIFF file specification, and implement this in my own code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [LibTIFF](http://www.libtiff.org/).